# mouseEventListener for each object in Processing

Tags: java, oop, mouseevent, processing

I`m using processing to implement a software like this:

There`s five balls(sphere) in a 3D space,each ball can be click,once I click one of the ball,there will be a balloon（in picture）pop out just like this:

[image]

In java ,like GUI programming,each component has its own mouseEventListener,but in processing,is there any API offer each sphere a listener for its own?

Answer (score 0):

I have dome similar things by having an array of the objects I want to press. Each object must have a mouseOver method, in this method you check if the mouse is inside your balloon for example an then return true. 
In your mousePress method check this method for every balloon and if the mouse it's over perform whatever you want.

Sample code for the balloon class:

```
Class Balloon{
  int posX, posY, width, height;

  Balloon(int posX, int posY, int width, int height){

    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

  }

  boolean mouseOver(){

    if(mouseX < (posX-width) && mouseX > posX){
      if(mouseY < (posY-height) && mouseY > posY){
        return true;
      }
    }       
    return false;

  }

}
```

Sample for the mousePress in the main class:

```
void mousePressed(){ 

  for(int i=0; i < ballons.length; i++){

    if(balloons[i].mouseOver()){
      //Perform your action
      break;
    }

  }

}
```

Regards Jose.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I have considered your advice before your answer,the solution isn`t flawless,once two balls are overlapped,one click may trigger two listener,this is weird,something like bubble up feature in javascript.